# Set linear layout as selected on Click Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I have multiple linear layouts inside a `ScrollView` .Each `linear layout` have a image on click of which i want to set the linear layout background as selected as we have in `listview` .

**XML**

```
<ScrollView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img1"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img2"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img3"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
                            android:layout_gravity="center" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/layout4"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="70dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/img4"
                            android:layout_width="90dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </ScrollView>
```

I have done like this onclick of the imageView:

```
layout1.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

But this is not giving me the desired output  .Please help me in this how we can do this

change the selected State :

```
public void changeState(){
        for (int i = 0; i < mainLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = mainLayout.getChildAt(i);
            child.setSelected(false);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a xml drawable in your drawable folder ex: `background_linear.xml`
write the below code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:state_selected="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
             <solid android:color="required_color_here"/>
       </shape>
</item>
```

Then set  `background_linear` as background for your `LinearLayout` in your xml layout.

And on click of image view call this method
`layout1.setSelected(true);`

To remove the selection you have to call same method by passing `false`.
If you have multiple `LinearLayout` then you should remember  which one was previously selected layout. To achieve this you can do this:
Define an `int` to store `id` of the previously selected view.

```
int previously_selected_layout;
```

And in on click of image view

```
 imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
     ((View)view.getParent()).setSelected(true);
     View v1=findViewById(previously_selected_layout);
     if(v1!=null) v1.setSelected(false);
     previously_selected_layout=view.getParent().getId();
  }
 });
```

If you don't want set `ClickListener` to every `ImageView` in java then set `onClick` property of  all  `ImageView` in xml to same method.

Comment: Praveen Please elaborate this more ??

Comment: how could i define this shape="rectangle"

Comment: on selection of other imageview previous selected layout is not getting deselected

Comment: For that you have to call `layout1.setSelected(false);`  additional work is you should remember which one was previously selected.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80449/discussion-between-gaurav-and-praveen).

Comment: @Gaurav What is your desired output

Comment: as i shared the xml i want on click of imageview i want the particular layout to be highlighted .i have 5 linear layout containing one imageview in each so onclick og image view i want to highlight the particular layout

Comment: Post your new xml layout written after my suggestion